# After joining three sql tables in codeigniter, can't find the desired id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

### Can not find the desired Id

I am joining three SQL tables in CodeIgniter. I can able to retrieve the data from three tables. But I face a problem in finding the proper id.

I put my three tables below:

#### books table:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `categoryId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_image` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `create_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','0') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '1 = published | 0 = unpublished'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

#### category table:

```
    CREATE TABLE `category` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `description` text NOT NULL,
      `tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

#### users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'U',
  `createdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

#### My Model:

```
public function get_books($limit, $offset)
{   
    /*=== SQL join ===*/
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->join('books', 'books.categoryId = category.id');
    $this->db->join('users', 'books.userId = users.id'); #...Join three sql table

    $this->db->order_by('books.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->where('books.status', '1');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Now I get the id of users in my joined table. **But I want books id as the main id.** How I could solve that problem?

Comment: Your query returns all the columns from all 3 tables. There is no **main** column.

Comment: I want to make the books table as my main table.@forpas

Comment: There is no *main table* or *main column*. Just drop `*` and select the columns that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As the previous answer**, you should not use the `'*'` this. You should write the select query manually, select whatever column you want from the tables.

To get the book's id as your desired id, you should change your model code as below.

**Model code**

```
public function get_books($limit, $offset)
{   
    $this->db->select('books.id, books.book_name, books.description, books.author, books.book_image, books.otherCol, category.category, users.name'); // You can add many more if you want.

    $this->db->from('books');
    $this->db->join('category', 'books.categoryId = category.id'); //2nd join
    $this->db->join('users', 'books.userId = users.id'); //3rd join

    $this->db->order_by('books.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->where('books.status', '1');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I think now you will get your desired *id* from the **books** table.

Comment: It's fixed my problem. This is what I want, Thanks @tumn

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `select *` in your query,
Signify which columns you want by their table names or table aliases, since you have 3 tables joined and all have an id column it doesn't know which id column you want from your query result,

```
$this->db->select('books.id, books.status, users.someData, etc.');
```

Comment: This query is okay until two tables join.

Comment: @TahmidNishat I explained your problem in my answer. You are joining multiple tables that have an "id" column, when you go to set values on whatever it is you are setting, it doesn't know which column you want since you have 3 columns returned from the query with the column name "id", of course it works when you only select from one table as it's the only table with an "id" column.

Answer (score 1):

below, i am just selecting all columns from books table. I have also made books the main table instead of the category table

```
public function get_books($limit, $offset)
{   
    /*=== SQL join ===*/
    $this->db->select('books.*');
    $this->db->from('books');
    $this->db->join('category', 'books.categoryId = category.id');
    $this->db->join('users', 'books.userId = users.id'); #...Join three sql table

    $this->db->order_by('books.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->where('books.status', '1');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: This query can not fetch the data from the other two tables. It should be like `$this->db->select('books.*, users.name, category.category );`